# How to change alter/tweak the system environment after the test build is done in vteststudio?

Tags: canoe

I have built a test unit in vtstudio and the exe is run in another machine(CANoe) that has a different system environment than mine. How is it possible to change it without changing the system environment in vtstudio. Reason for this is I have to build test executables that should be usable in multiple machine across geographical locations. The computer that is used for execution does not have vtstudio, it has only canoe. Regards

I built a test exe and tried running it in another machine. It throwed a error saying "THe network assignments of the vTESTstudio could not be applied without errors.
If you update the CANoe environment in vTESTstudio and deploy a new build of the test unit again the problem can be fixed."

Is it possible to export the CANoe environment that is running in other machine and place it in my machine vTESTstudio and rebuild the test.

Remember I am building a test exe(.vtuexe) and that exe is run by a different person on a vehicle far away. He will not be able to update the environment as he is not using vTESTstudio.